# getting domain details and portrait_id and landscape_id for openX

Tags: android, openx

I just downloaded the OpenX android sdk and tried to point it to the domain which was created locally but looks it isnt working fine for me.

The OXMAdBanner in the layout looks something like :

```
<com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.views.OXMAdBanner
        android:id="@+id/Advertisment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        domain="http://dev.com/openx/www/images/"
        portrait_id="137298"
        landscape_id="138660"
        change_interval="10000" />
```

My question is how fo i get the domain, portrait_id and landcape_id details for the server configured locally.

If i hit this Url in browser http://dev.com/openx/www/images/ (url modified) i can see the list of images as per the below image
[image].

Any pointers on what am i doing wrong here or how do i get the details of the domain/portrait_id/lanscape_id.

Note : - I have not modified the activity which comes in default with the OpenX sdk sample project.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? If you got the solution, please share. I am also facing problem on getting domain/portrait_id/lanscape_id from my own server. I have installed revive server on my own server.

Answer (score 0):

The domain, portraitID, landscapeID are provided to you by OpenX once you create an account with them. You can't use your own domain!

Comment: If I am not wrong, Openx is open source right? So, if we setup openx or revive on our own server, then from where can we get portrait id, landscape id, and what is the domain url? I have installed revive on my own server. I followed the documentation too. But i didn't get these values. Please help me regarding this problem..

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.openx.com/sdk/ for OpenX Enterprise Ad Server .

OpenX Sales their Openx Source PHP Code to Revive Ad Server Team .

To Delivery Ads on Mobile App using openx-2.8.11 or Revive-Adserver(http://www.revive-adserver.com/releases/revive-adserver-3.0.0.zip) you need to write Mobile SDKs.

Ad Units in OpenX Enterprise - Ad Unit ID

Zones in Revive Ad Server (OpenX Source) - Zone ID

You can write the Objective-C code to Send Ad Request & Receive Ad Response(Banner,Rich Media,Video)

mAdserv -Open Source Mobile Ad Server

Download the mAdserv , you can have SDK for Android and iOS.

Their SDK also Open Source .

You use or customize the codes of sdk

Comment: If I am not wrong, Openx is open source right? So, if we setup openx or revive on our own server, then from where can we get portrait id, landscape id, and what is the domain url? I have installed revive on my own server. I followed the documentation too. But i didn't get these values. Please help me regarding this problem..