# How to get portrait_id, Landscape_id and domain details for android from revive server

Tags: android, android-orientation, openx

I have installed revive ad server in my own server. And I am using Android SDK of openx for android. How to get portrait_id, Landscape_id and domain details for android from revive server. If I am not wrong, revive and openx are same, openx is old name of revive ad server. I have gone through this thread of SO: 
      [getting domain details and portrait_id and landscape_id for openX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376925/getting-domain-details-and-portrait-id-and-landscape-id-for-openx)

I don't get the required answer there. I asked my query in comment also, but no one is replying. So, how to get these values from revive server?